# Calculating group percentages, is there a better way

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a datatable with 3 categorical variables: primarydx, NumDx, and ContractType.

```
primarydx <- rep(c("AB","MT"),10)
NumDx <- rep(c(1,2,3), length.out=20 )
ContractType <- rep( c("W","L","W","W","W") , length.out=20)
SecDx3 <- data.table(primarydx, NumDx, ContractType)
```

I want to calculate the percentage of records of each ContractType within primarydx and NumDx. The following code works:

```
Num <-SecDx3[ , .(n=.N), by=.(primarydx, NumDx, ContractType)]
denom <- SecDx3[ , .(d=.N), by=.(primarydx, NumDx)]
pct <- merge(Num,denom)
pct[,pct:=n/d][]
```

Is there a better way?

I did find something like:

```
SecDx3[,{
  d =.N
  .SD[, .(pct = .N/d), by=.(primarydx, NumDx, ContractType)]
  }, by=.(primarydx, NumDx)]
```

but this returns an error "The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,1,20). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (20)." which I don't understand.

Thanks for your help,

David

Comment: What do you mean `percentage of records`

Comment: Also share some sample data

Comment: I think you have a typo, using as.data.table on multiple objects instead of data.table(...)

Comment: Anyway, your approach is pretty standard. There's also `DT[, .N, by=.(ContractType, primarydx, NumDx)][, .(ContractType, N, d = sum(N), pct = N/sum(N)), by=.(primarydx, NumDx)]`

Comment: You mean 'proportion of' rather than 'percentage of', since your results sum to 1.00 not 100%

Answer (score 1):

Probably faster will be

```r
SecDx3[, d:=.N, by=.(primarydx, NumDx)
       ][, {
           n<-.N
           .(n=n, d=d[1L], pct=n/d[1L])
         },
         by=.(primarydx, NumDx, ContractType)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were close with your second code chunk, but it seems you can only use each column once in the `by`s. I have found this works:

```
SecDx3[, {n <- .N; .SD[, list(pct = .N / n), by = .(ContractType)]}, by = .(primarydx, NumDx)]

    primarydx NumDx ContractType       pct
 1:        AB     1            W 0.7500000
 2:        AB     1            L 0.2500000
 3:        MT     2            L 0.2500000
 4:        MT     2            W 0.7500000
 5:        AB     3            W 1.0000000
 6:        MT     1            W 1.0000000
 7:        AB     2            W 0.6666667
 8:        AB     2            L 0.3333333
 9:        MT     3            W 0.6666667
10:        MT     3            L 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Frank's approach above, since the numerator and denominator are not really needed, the following code seems compact and clear:

```
SecDx3[, .N, by=.(ContractType, primarydx, NumDx)
       ][, .(pct = N/sum(N)), by=.(primarydx, NumDx)]
```